# Remove elements from a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list and I would like to remove some elements from it.

Problem I ran into is that If I want to remove more than one element, then I lose control of what I'm removing.

See, the code `mylist.Removeat(index) does the work just fine, however, if I have a list o let's say 10 elements and I need to remove 6 randomly, I don't seem to find a function that removes them all at once, instead, it removes the first element, then the second and so on and it is not really what I want.

Thanks,

EDIT:

Thanks all for your comments, the best way was doing a loop descending like this:

```
            int img_count = img.Count;

            for (int i = img_count; i >0; --i)
            {
                if (images_to_delete.Contains(i)) img.RemoveAt(i);
            }
```

Comment: As long as they get removed, why does it matter how?

Comment: Why is that not what you want?  My guess is that it is removing the lowest index first, changing the index ordering, and screwing it up. Have you tried creating a 2nd list of items to remove and doing a except?

Comment: is there a reason why you need them all removed at the same time?

Comment: Code to "remove X random elements" with a loop *will work* if you compute the random number based on the *remaining elements* after each `RemoveAt` and are truly getting a *random number* - maybe the "random" number is always 0 or otherwise not-random? The code is not creating a *new* Random object each loop .. is it?

Comment: I'm guessing they're saying that they want to remove say indexes `1,2,5` at once. But once they remove 1, removing (2) will actually remove the item that was *originally* at index 3. They want a function that takes in the original indexes (in this case `1,2,5`) and knows how to handle the shifting indexes. I'm not sure one exists, but it shouldn't be hard to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that once you delete an item at a certain index, all the other indexes shift. Like if you had an array of `{"a", "b", "c"}`, and wanted to remove `a` and `b` by passing in `indexes = [0,1]`. Once you call `removeAt(0)`, now "b" is at index 0.

One way to handle it is to notice the fact that only *higher* indexes get shifted. So if you remove the 5th element for example, 0-4 are still going to have the same meaning; only 5 and up are affected.

Because of this, you can just remove the indexes in descending order (highest to lowest)! For example:

```
var vals = new[]{ "a", "b", "c" };
RemoveMultiple(vals, 0, 1);
```

and then RemoveMultiple looks like this:

```
public void RemoveMultiple<T>(List<T> list, params int[] indexes)
{
   // if this next line gives you a compiler error, you need to include
   // linq by putting a "using System.Linq;" at the very top of the file.
   var sortedIndexes = indexes.OrderByDescending(i => i);
   foreach(var indexToRemove in sortedIndexes)
   {
      list.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
   }
}
```

That should work!

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, removing in descending order did the trick

Comment: +1 -- I thought that might be what was being asked, and was about to post the same solution with sorting the indexes in descending order. The "random" threw me off though :)

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't extremely clear, but if you want to remove a specified number of elements  at random indexes from the List here is a method that will do that. (This is example is with a list of String objects, but you could change it to use any object of course).

```
private static List<String> strList = new List<String>();        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            strList.AddRange("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z".Split(','));
            removeRandomItemsFromList(strList, 8);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",strList.ToArray()));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void removeRandomItemsFromList(List<String> list, int numToRemove){
            Random randGenerator = new Random();
            if(numToRemove >= list.Count()){
                Console.WriteLine("Num to remove is as big or larger than list size, clearing list.");
                list.Clear();
                return;                
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < numToRemove; i++)
            {
                int randIndex = randGenerator.Next(list.Count - 1); //get random index within bounds of list
                list.RemoveAt(randIndex);
            }
        }
```

When I ran it I got the output:
B,C,F,H,I,J,K,M,N,O,P,Q,R,U,V,X,Y,Z

But of course it will usually be different since it's removing random items.

Comment: I'm assuming they were using random to mean "arbitrarily specified by a caller" instead of the actual definition of "random"... The meaning of "random" has definitely gotten butchered colloquially :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I guess I confused everyone with the random statement. Actually I have a second list with the elements the user selected to be deleted and needed to remove those from the main list. See my EDIT, there I put the answer. Thanks for your suggestions!